# Axiomatic explanation of why the volume of a parallelepiped is equal to the area of its base times its height

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $V_n$ be the volume on the set of polytopes in $\mathbb R^n$, *defined axiomatically*, i.e. a functional, that assigns to each polytope $P\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ a real number $V_n(P)\ge 0$ in such a way that the following conditions are fulfilled:

1. For the unit hypercube $C\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ 
   $$
   V_n(C)=1,
   $$
2. If $P\cap Q=\varnothing$, then 
   $$
   V_n(P\cup Q)=V_n(P)+V_n(Q),
   $$
3. If $P$ is made from $Q$ by a *motion*, then
   $$
   V_n(P)=V_n(Q).
   $$
   Question:

   > Is there a simple way to prove that the $n$-th volume of a parallelepiped $P_{a_1,...,a_n}$ spanned by $n$ vectors $a_1,...,a_n$ is the poduct of the $n-1$-th volume of $P_{a_1,...,a_{n-1}}$ and the height of $P_{a_1,...,a_n}$ with respect to the base $P_{a_1,...,a_{n-1}}$,
   >   $$
   > V_n(P_{a_1,...,a_n})=V_{n-1}(P_{a_1,...,a_{n-1}})\cdot \left|\text{pr}_{\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}^\perp}(a_n)\right|
   > $$
   >   ?

P.S. I asked this also in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209745/axiomatic-explanation-of-why-the-volume-of-a-parallelepiped-is-equal-to-the-area).

Comment: You could arrange many copies of the epipd in a gid and roughly estimate how many unit cubes these contain together

Comment: Hagen, I don't understand. A priori, $V_n$ is not the Jordan measure. What do you mean by estimating?

Comment: In the plane, this is [Euclid I:35](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI35.html); the extension to three-dimensional space is [Euclid XI:29](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXI/propXI29.html), XI:30, and XI:31.  The ideas used there to get from the 2-dimensional result to the 3-dimensional result will also work to get from the $n$-dimensional result to the $(n+1)$-dimensional result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=P_{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a parallelopiped with edge vectors $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$.  I claim that $P$ is scissors-congruent to $P'=P_{a_1+ra_2,a_2\dots,a_n}$ for any $|r|\leq 1$.  To show this, think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as having $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ as its standard basis (it will not matter that this basis is not orthonormal because we will only be using translations).  In this basis, $P=[0,1]^n$ (up to a translation), and we wish to transform it into $P'=Q\times[0,1]^{n-2}$, where $Q$ is the parallelogram with edges $(1,r)$ and $(0,1)$.  This $Q$ is scissors-congruent to $[0,1]^2$ by chopping off a triangle and translating it (as in [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ParallelogramArea.svg)).  Crossing this cutting and translation with $[0,1]^{n-2}$, we obtain that $P$ and $P'$ are scissors-congruent.

Now by iterating transformations of this kind (for different orderings of the vectors), we can transform $P$ into a parallelopiped with the same base $P_{a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}}$ but for which $a_n$ has been replaced with its projection onto the orthogonal complement of the base.  For parallelopipeds of this form, it is clear that $V_n(P)$ is proportional to $\|a_n\|$.  Furthermore, if we consider such parallelopipeds with $\|a_n\|=1$, allow the base to vary within the orthogonal complement of $a_n$, and write $W_{n-1}(P_{a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}})=V_n(P)$, $W_{n-1}$ satisfies the axioms for $V_{n-1}$.  By induction, we know that the axioms uniquely determine $V_{n-1}$ (at least on parallelopipeds), so $W_{n-1}=V_{n-1}$.  The desired formula for $V_n(P)$ now follows.

Comment: Eric, I don't understand the details. Let $n=3$. You suggest to replace $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ by $(a_1+ra_2,a_2,a_3)$. OK, after that the first two vectors become orthogonal, let us denote them $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$. But what we do next? If we replace $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ by $(b_1,b_2+rb_3,b_3)$, then the first two vectors can again become non-orthogonal. There must be further tricks?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: If you want to (say) make $a_3$ orthogonal to $a_1$ and $a_2$, let $ra_1+sa_2$ be its orthogonal projection onto their span, and subtract $ra_1$ and then $sa_2$ from $a_3$.

Comment: Ah, OK! Yes, thank you!